# get the port on localhost on which service is running

Tags: vb.net, service, localhost

i have a service on my computer (personal computer and app is third party). Everytime i start it it runs on a localhost port like :

`localhost:13133`

Now 1 want this port number on which service is running. Is there any command or code i can use or read some file where it is stored everytime a service is started? I cannot put a fixed number in my code and want to read this everytime it changes or is run.

Please help?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

ok got it. In case someone wants a solution :

1) run cmd with netstat command output response to a text file

2) parse the text file for your process id or name

Done :)